# Grab param from string and convert to array php

Tags: php, regex

I have input string from users. this input from users are unpredictable. it's mean user can input any string as they like.
I would like to filter the input that match following pattern and return it as an array

These following string pattern should works:

```
product=bag, product=tshirt, product=shoes
```

---

```
product=bag status=sold, product=jeans, product=shoes
```

---

```
product=all
```

I would like the output as array like below :

```
Array(
 [0] => Array
  (
    [product] => bag
    [status]  => sold
  )

 [1] => Array
  (
    [product] => jeans
  )

 [2] => Array
  (
    [product] => shoes
  )
)
```

I guess it can be achieved by use preg_match_all() beside explode. Anyone can give me example using preg_match_all ? or any other ways are ok for me as long as the best method.

```
$string = 'product=bag status=sold, product=tshirt, product=shoes';
$m = preg_match_all('/needregexrulehere/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: @ethrbunny Sorry, but he's not using the **e** modifier :)

Comment: to clarify: this is should php function not command line, all params above is defined in variable. the point is I just split the array above as an array as output above. let me know if you need more clarify. thx

Comment: @ethrbunny try it yourself !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this, you can do something like this:

```
$return = array();
foreach( str_getcsv( $string) as $line) {
    parse_str( str_replace( ' ' , '&', $line), $temp);
    $return[] = $temp;
}
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/qTClqt):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => bag
            [status] => sold
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => tshirt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => shoes
        )

)
```

I will leave error checking / input sanitation up to the OP.

Comment: +1 Nice, and I was going to write a solution with explode() & preg_match() xD